# Geometric proof that the chord of a larger central angle is longer

Tags: geometry, circles

In a circle, as we increase a central angle from 0 to 180 degrees, the length of the subtended chord grows, from 0 to the diameter of the circle. My question is how to prove this. I.e., that the chord subtended by a larger central angle will be longer.

This is quite easy to see visually and easy to prove with trigonomry and calculus (e.g., see [Will the chord of a larger central angle be longer than the chord of a smaller central angle?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1601606/will-the-chord-of-a-larger-central-angle-be-longer-than-the-chord-of-a-smaller-c)) but I was wondering how to prove it with much more basic geometry.

To use a specific example, consider a circle with radius R, and a central angle of 61 degrees. We want to prove that the length of the chord is more than R. Indeed, for a central angle of 60 degrees, the chord length is exactly R (the central angle and the chord make an equilateral triangle, so the chord length is also R), so because 61 > 60 the chord for 61 should be longer than R. The question is how to prove this without knowledge of trigonometric functions or their properties.

Comment: See Wikipedia: [Hinge Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hinge_theorem), or ProofWiki: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Hinge_Theorem

Comment: It is true that the ***larger*** is the central angle $\theta$; where $0^0 \le \theta \le 180^0$, the ***larger*** is the subtended chord L. However, L is NOT directly proprotional to $\theta$!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Player3236's comment really says it all; I'm just going to place those links here so the question reads as "answered."

Wikipedia has an entry for the [Hinge Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hinge_theorem), and ProofWiki has a [proof](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Hinge_Theorem).

For the sake of completeness, I should mention that this theorem appeared in Euclid's Elements. You can see, for instance, [this link](https://mathcs.clarku.edu/%7Edjoyce/java/elements/elements.html) for more from those books.